# Angular JS directive ng-app is not recognized

Tags: angularjs

Today is the first when i started reading about Angular JS and I tried to do a very basic thing after reading from a tutorial.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
    <title></title>    
</head>
<body>
Name:
<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-app="name" /> {{ name }}

<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I downloaded and added the angular js library from GitHUB 1.4.x(latest). I expect the name to be written on the fly when user types in the textbox but nothing happens. What am i missing for this basic set up ?

P.S. - I am using an HTML page in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I do not see a reference to script file declaring the angular module called 'name'

Comment: you seem to be using `data-ng-app` twice; I suspect you want `data-ng-model="name"` instead.

Comment: oh I am so sorry. Don't know why i missed that. You are right Claies.

Comment: also, that video is out of date, and portions of it will not work correctly with anything later than angular 1.2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some minor adjustments to your code, and it works just fine:

```
<html ng-app="">
        <head>
            <title></title>    
        </head>
        <body>
        Name:
        <br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" /> {{ name }}

        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

A working code pen can be seen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPWyaR

Answer (score 2):

I note a few things.

a) No reference to script file which should contain an angular module declaration.
b) The input references an angular app named "name" but it is immediately closed
c) No controller declared
d) data-ng-app needs older version of angular. I suggest use 1.3.5

I will do the following corrections to get it working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rfXgNl6ugqSmlwXOaHIN?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

<head>
  <title>
    My First Angular App
  </title>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('name', []);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'World';
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="name">
  Name:
  <br />
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
    {{name}}
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/aze39fjq/

change the html tag to: `<html ng-app>`

change your input directive to `data-ng-model="name"`

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    Name:
    <br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" /> {{ name }} 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```